# sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Xcode app which I am updating to the latest iOS. I now notice that on building I have the following error/warning:

/ConfViewController.m:198:46: 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h

From what I have read I should start to use "NSURLSession" but how do I use "NSURLSession" in my code, or am I looking at this incorrectly?

My code:

```
NSString *deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice]name];
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"devicename=%@",deviceName];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain/sysscripts/conf/devicelookup17.php"];


        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

//The ERROR point
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        //NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
           // NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);

           // NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
            NSInteger roomid = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"roomid"] integerValue];
           // NSLog(@"%ld",(long)success);
            //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)roomid);
            NSString *RoomID =  [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)roomid];
           // NSLog(@"%@", RoomID);

            NSString *firstString = @"http://www.mydomain/apps/conf/lon/dt/devices/ /template17.php";
           // NSLog(@"%@", firstString);

            NSString *roomID = RoomID;
           // NSLog(@"%@", roomID);

            NSString *newString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:roomID];
          //  NSLog(@"%@", newString);

            NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString: newString];
            NSLog(@"%@", url2);

            NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];


           // ConfViewController *navex =[[ConfViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            //[self presentViewController:navex animated:YES completion:NULL];
            [webView loadRequest:request2];



        }
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Replace

   ```
   NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
   ```

   with

   ```
   [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {


   }] resume];
   ```
2. Put the entire code after the `sendSynchronousRequest` line in the completion block (between the braces).
3. Replace

   ```
   if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
   ```

   with

   ```
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
   NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
   if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300)
   ```
4. Replace `urlData` with `data`.
5. Delete

   ```
   NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
   NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
   ```

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your reply. I have changed my code to yours but I have an error at: NSInteger statusCode = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response.statusCode; with the error message of: Property 'statusCode' not found on object of type 'NSURLResponse'. Any ideas as to why? Again, many thanks for your time.

Comment: Try `[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]` or in two lines `NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;` `NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;`

Comment: Hi, that cleared that error but now I have an error on: if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) with the error use of undeclared identifier 'statusCode'